# multiple select dropdown with checkbox in flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, combobox, flex4

I am trying to implement multiple select on ComboBox with check boxes in flex 4.1. By default the combo box closes after every select, is there any way to override that default function?

Answer (score 0):

1) // is there any way to override that default function?

In combobox the open/close of the popupList was handled by **DropDownController.as** in **DropDownListBase.as** i hope u can override **closeDropDown** method to prevent close.But ensure you need to handle the close when click outside the combobox.

```
override public function closeDropDown(commit:Boolean):void
 {
    // your logic goes here
    // call super if needed to close
    //super.closeDropDown(commit);
 }
```

For preventing the default behavior You can also use the below methods on close event (or ItemClick event if it has one)

```
event.preventDefault();
```

which Cancels an event's default behavior if that behavior can be canceled.

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

which Prevents processing of any event listeners in nodes subsequent to the current node in the event flow.

There are lot of flex example out there for combobox with checkbox itemrenderer before u post any question in stackOverflow do a Google search.

I hope this will help you

https://code.google.com/p/combocheck/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

http://www.flexicious.com/home/FlexMultiSelectComboBox